# Eclipse - set the C++ standard

Tags: c++, standards, eclipse-cdt

ALL,

I'm worjking under RHEL 8 with the latest (2021-09) Eclipse version 4.21.0.

I'd like to set a C++ standard to be c++11, since I need a compatibility with the RHEL7.

I tried to follow instructyion I found on a different SO questions but none was sufficient, since many options were removed in this latest Eclipse version.

Could someone please give me a way to set it up for the latest Eclipse release, please?

TIA!!

Comment: From the main menu select *Project->Properties*. In the left pane tree expand *C/C++ Build* and click Settings. In the right pane select the *Tool Settings* tab. In the tree in the *Tool Settings* tab, expand *C++ Compiler* and click *Dialect*. Pick desired Standard from *Language Standard* drop-down.

Comment: The latest Eclipse version is 2022-03 (4.23), 2021-09 is two releases behind.

Comment: @user4581301, I don't see a `Tool Settings` tab. All I see are `Container Settings`, `Binary Parsers` and `Error Parsers`.

Comment: Container settings suggests you've created a Docker (or similar) project, not a C/C++ project.

Comment: @user4581301, nope, all I did was to do File->Import->C/C++ and then used Linux GCC one. Is there a way to change it? Or check to make sure its the right one?

Comment: I haven't run into that problem, so I can't offer fixes. Recommendation: Make a brand-new C++ project and make sure you get the correct settings panes and can build good ol' Hello World. If you have pre-exiting workspaces, make a copy and see if Eclipse can make things right by updating the old workspace.

Comment: As said by howlger, my version is old. I will try to get a newer version and see what will happen. Thx.

Comment: @user4581301, for some unknown reason the project is importing as a Container. All I'm doing is "File->Import...->Existing code as Makefile Project->", then selecting GCC in the toolchain and choosing the proper directory. Also - I'm not in the container. This is a real hardware (not even inside VM). I will probably have to liove with it for now... :(